# Android textview and Menu

Tags: android, menu, textview

i have a textview and a Menu , the textview is currently showing at the bottom of the screen and when menu pressed ,currently the menu hide the textview ,but i want the textview automatically move upwords so that everybody can see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/android_bg"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="50dp" 
         android:background="@drawable/navigationbar">
         <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:id="@+id/banner_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/bannertext_angies_list">></TextView>

            <Button
            android:layout_width="55dp"  
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/sign_out_button_clicked_button"

                android:id="@+id/signout"/>

    </RelativeLayout>  
    <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >






    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <TableRow
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Thank you, your report has been"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Thanks_to_submission1"/>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >
                <TextView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:paddingLeft="70dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="submitted successfuly!"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Thanks_to_submission2"/>
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/submitbutton"
                android:id="@+id/submitreport_providertype_button"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/searchlist_button"
                android:id="@+id/search_list_button"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bigdeal_button"
                android:id="@+id/big_deal_button"/>

      </TableRow>


</TableLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

            <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"  
            android:onClick="true" 
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:text="Or visit our website at" /> 

           <TextView 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="40dp" 
           android:id="@+id/link" 
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:autoLink="web" 
           android:linksClickable="true" 
           android:layout_gravity="center" 
           android:textSize="14sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"  

           android:onClick="true" 
           android:textColor="#000000" 
           android:text="@string/link" /> 


         </LinearLayout>

        <TextView 
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" 
            android:text="Or visit our website at" /> 


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That's not really supported by Android, and it's by design. The idea is that you can use the full screen for your UI, and the menu takes up part of the space when you need to select it. You don't want to worry about text views and other things while the menu is up. This is better than the iPhone, where you permanently have to give up screen space for menu items. If something is really important, then move it away from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: May as well make this an answer. Hold on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really supported by Android, and it's by design. The idea is that you can use the full screen for your UI, and the menu takes up part of the space when you need to select it. You don't want to worry about text views and other things while the menu is up. This is better than the iPhone, where you permanently have to give up screen space for menu items. If something is really important, then move it away from the bottom of the screen.

If you're really bent on moving stuff around, you could intercept `Activity.onPrepareOptionsMenu` and move things around in your UI, although the function wasn't really meant for that purpose. Then matching call is `onOptionsMenuClosed`.